# How to find *.o file by KERNEL level Makefile

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, kernel

Generally in kernel level `make file` contain

```
$(CONFIG_SERIAL_DEVICE) += serial.o
```

When we are making user level `make file` then it'll find `.o` file from that particular folder. But in this, where `serial.o` exist??

Comment: Read [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt).

Answer (score 1):

For Example

```
drivers/serial/Makefile:obj-$(CONFIG_SERIAL_TXX9)+=serial_txx9.o
```

this Makefile in kernel serial driver will build depending .config of respective kernel code. It will pick details like build statically or dynamically from .config.

Comment: can you elaborate more on that.

Comment: @Vikrant The .config is generated based on menuconfig selections.  When make traverses the kernel source, it will use the CONFIG_* options in the .config to select which source files are compiled.  Look in the subdirectory Makefiles to see how they are conditionally compiled based on these CONFIG_* settings.